# Float: right causing element to pushed to next line in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have four elements in a div. Out of them, I want the last element to be pushed to the extreme right. I am using float: right for the last element. This results in the last element to be pushed to the right end of the next line in Firefox. For other browsers, rendering is absolutely fine. I cannot make any modification in the HTML.
How can this be fixed?

Comment: Please provide us with some code so we can help you better.

Comment: Are the browser windows the same width?

Comment: make sure your container has width 100% and it is not taking more then that!

Answer (score 1):

IF you Share your Code ,I can Help you Better.But I have a few suggestions:

> 1)Use of `width` Property to all Elements.(Width's Element1 + Width's Element2 + Width's Element3 + Width's Element4 <= 100%)
>
> 2)Use of `box-sizing:border-box` Property to all Elements.
>
> 3)Use of `float:left' For the first three elements and` float:right` for last Element.

**This is example :**

```css
.el1, .el2, .el3, .el4 {
    width: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background-color: #000;
    color: orange;
    float: left;
}

.el4 {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="el1">Element1</div>
    <div class="el2">Element2</div>
    <div class="el3">Element3</div>
    <div class="el4">Element4</div>
</div>
```

This Work For Me well,I Hope Work For You!

Answer (score 0):

Check this `fiddle` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/qsoahjo7/). This works fine in Firefox. Maybe you can adjust the CSS.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
}

.el {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.element4 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el element4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Firefox itself.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=488725

I have fixed it using firefox specific styles:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
//your styles here
}
```